# Outlook Clean Up Tool Conversations View not available in 2nd Email Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I manage three different Outlook Company Inboxes.  I am only able to access the Clean Up tool and View Conversations in my primary email account.  Is it possible to gain access to these features in the other two Inboxes that I monitor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to better solve your problem, please provide more information about your case:

- Does this issue occur in Outlook client? If so, what's the version of
  your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make
  sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.
- For the "Clean Up tool and View Conversations" you mentioned, do you
  mean the two in the figure below?

  [image] [image]
- What are your three accounts? Are they personal accounts, shared
  mailboxes, or something else?
- When you log in accounts that do not display these options to other
  computers, does the problem still exist?

Comment: I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread. Should you need more help on this, you can feel free to post back.